# 18.04: Laptop with 4K display doesn't keep preferred resolution at full HD

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, system-settings

My laptop (Lenovo YOGA C930-13IKB) is running 18.04LTS.
The screen is 4k but because of scaling issues in multiple applications and use an external full HD monitor I prefer to have the laptop screen at 1920x1080 @ 100% scaling.

The problem is that randomly these settings seem to get lost and it will revert to 4K @ 200%.
This will also cause the external monitor to scale 200% (which is useless) and after correcting the settings I often need to restart gnome or the entire machine to fix lingering scaling issues.

These issues come up randomly after for example: plugging in a monitor, rebooting, coming out of sleep and I think sometimes even after coming back from the lock screen

For what it's worth I use a StartTech usb to hdmi displaylink adapter (USB32HD4K) to attach external monitors but it should be noted that these settings also change randomly when no external monitor is being used.
I don't always use the same monitor because of work from home and flexible work spaces, sometimes an external monitor might be 4K but I still prefer using full HD.

**Is there a way to simply disable higher resolutions and scaling from being used automatically.**

or

**Can I set a default settings that it should try to enforce for all monitors by default.**